# Trying to Run this code whenever Sheet specific Cell is update or Specific range is update

Tags: excel, vba

I have updated my code to Worksheet Change event that whenever the `Sheet15.Range("$B$2")` values goes change or update my code will run.

But it does not work i do not know why?

And one more thing i want That same value (which is copied) by below code should be pasted on

```
sheet8.Range(G18:G)
```

by using this technique

```
lastR5 = Sheet8.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated towards the problem.

Mycode.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Sheet15.Range("$B$2")
If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        
          Dim lastR4 As Long
lastR4 = Sheet4.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row on E:E col
Sheet4.Range("F11:F" & lastR4).Value = Sheet15.Range("A" & _
   WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheet1.Range("B7").Value, Sheet15.Range("A:A"), 0)).Offset(0, 1)
      
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @FaneDuru Please have a look into this.

Comment: Do you try running the above code in Sheet15? And do you want running the code if the value in cell "B2" is changed?

Comment: @FaneDuru, Yes i tried but nothing happen?

Comment: And you do not use the Target value in any way. Is this what you want? Only to run the code when a change happens in "B2"? If yes, please try the code I posted. If not, please better describe what is to be done...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the event code belongs to Sheet15 code module, please use the next:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address <> "$B$2" Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim lastR4 As Long
    lastR4 = Sheet4.Range("E" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row on E:E col
    Sheet4.Range("F11:F" & lastR4).Value = Sheet15.Range("A" & _
       WorksheetFunction.match(Sheet1.Range("B7").Value, Sheet15.Range("A:A"), 0)).Offset(0, 1)
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

If the B2 cell will keep a result of a formula, you should use sheet `Calculate~ event, in this way:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Static b2Val As String
    If b2Val = "" Then b2Val = Sheet15.Range("B2").Value: GoTo OverCheck
    If Sheet15.Range("B2").Value = b2Val Then Exit Sub
    
OverCheck:
    Dim lastR4 As Long
    lastR4 = Sheet4.Range("E" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row on E:E col
    Sheet4.Range("F11:F" & lastR4).Value = Sheet15.Range("A" & _
       WorksheetFunction.match(Sheet1.Range("B7").Value, Sheet15.Range("A:A"), 0)).Offset(0, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: If Target.Address <> "$B$2" Then Exit Sub How to add Sheet15 in this line

Comment: @Learning: No need of it... It works on the active sheet which is this one.

Comment: Yes i know it. but B2 value will be automatically change it won't be an active sheet. Just  set trigger on it.

Comment: @Learning: I cannot get you... What do you want meaning? Where is the problem if it is not qualified using the worksheet? It will always work the same, since the active sheet is Sheet15. It will always refer this Sheet15.

Comment: I am trying to saying that If Sheet9 is open and Sheet15.Range(B2) value has been changed by formula so the code still will work. I am just clarifying it .

Comment: @Learning: Does B2 cell value is the result of a formula? If yes, you should use `Calculate` event, with some minor changes of the code. But **you should state it**!

Comment: FaneDuru, No its the result of a Code B2 values will be change by a code. I was not aware that was necessary to metnioned.

Comment: Then, nothing wrong will happen with the existing code. But, in case you change your mind and want it to be the result of the formula, I will edit the answer and I will also post a piece of code done for sheet `Calculate` event.